# Many-one-reductions with finite image

Tags: computability, undecidability, recursion-theory

Let $K$ be the halting set and suppose $K \leq_m A$ (under some function $f$), that is, $K$ is many-one-reducible to $A$.

1. How can $f(K)$ be a finite set?
2. Why if‌ $B$ is recursive, is $f^{-1}(B)$ also recursive?

Comment: There are no restrictions on the type of reduction?

Answer (score 4):

As the name suggests, a many-one reduction can map many instances of $K$ onto a single instance of $A$.  If there are no restrictions on the power of $f$, then you can pick some $a\in A$ and $b\notin A$ and then define
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
a &\text{ if }x\in K\\
b &\text{ if }x\notin K\,.
\end{cases}$$

However, if $f$ is restricted to be computable then the image of $f$ is necessarily infinite. This is because every finite set is computable so, if the image of $f$ were finite, you'd have a computable reduction from the halting set to a computable set, which is impossible because that would mean the halting set would be computable too.

If $B$ is recursive and $f$ is computable then you can decide whether $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ just by checking whether $f(x)\in B$. If $B$ isn't recursive or $f$ isn't computable, all the bets are off.

Comment: @PålGD $K$ is standard notation? Maybe if everybody teaches from the same book.

Comment: @Raphael $K$ has been used to denote the halting set since the days of Gödel and Post.  Every text book on recursion theory (e.g. Soare, Rogers, Odifreddi), all use $K$ to denote this set.  Post called Gödel's diagonal set, $K = \{e \mid e \in W_e\}$ the _complete set_ because every c.e. set $W_e$ is computable in $K$ [Soare, 2009].  I think cs.sx should accept $K$ as standard notation here.

Comment: @PålGD I know at least $H$ (for "Halteproblem").

Comment: There is a main problem. $f(K)$ is an infinite set is false. how do you say  " the image of f is necessarily infinite"

Comment: @PålGD,  would you please  help me about my last comment?

Comment: David, would you please answer to my comment?

Comment: @Homan I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "$f(K)$ is an infinite set is false"? I consider both the case that $f(K)$ is infinite and that it is finite. And my answer explains why $f(K)$ can't be infinite if $f$ is computable: it would contradict the undecidability of the halting problem.